# $\mathbb Z$-formality of spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-graded-algebras, formality

*A topological space $X$ is $\mathbb Z$-formal, if the singular cochain complex $C^*(X,\mathbb Z)$ is
quasi-isomorphic to $H^*(X, \mathbb Z)$ as an augmented differential graded ring.*

---

It's quite simple to write down specific quasi-isomorphisms to show that the Spheres $S^n$ are $\mathbb Q$-formal spaces by fixing a volume form $v \in \Omega^n(S^n)$ and considering the maps $H^*(S^n)=\operatorname{span}(1,[v]) \to \Omega^*(S^n)$ sending $1$ to the $1$-form and $[v]$ to $v$
and the canonical map $C^*(S^n) \to \Omega^*$.

Is it also possible to show the $\mathbb Z$-formality of the Spheres $S^n$ by writing down specific quasi-isomorphisms, or is it easier to use another method for showing $\mathbb Z$-formality?

Comment: I am probably missing something here: if you map 1 to 1 and a generator $g$ of $H^n(S^n,\mathbb{Z})$ to a closed element of $C^n(S^n,\mathbb{Z})$ with cohomology class $g$, doesn't that give you a quasi-isomorphism over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @abx Your reasoning shows that $H^*(S^n)$ and $C^*(S^n)$ are quasi-isomorphic as cochain complexes.  Formality is the *much stronger* condition that they are quasi-isomorphic as differential graded algebras.

Comment: @A.S. (see previous comment)

Comment: If we try to construct a map of $A_\infty$-algebras $F:H^*(S^n)\to C^*(S^n)$ by induction on $k$ (indexing the operations $F^k:H^*(S^n)^{\otimes k}\to C^*(S^n)$) whose $k=1$ component $F^1:H^*(S^n)\to C^*(S^n)$ induces the identity map on cohomology, then we run into potential obstructions when $k\equiv 2\mod n$.

Comment: What is wrong with the following? Introduce a simplicial structure on $S^n$. We get a zig-zag of algebra quasi-isomorphisms $C^*(S^n; \Bbb Z) \to C^*_\Delta(S^n;\Bbb Z) \xleftarrow{} H^*(S^n;\Bbb Z)$, the first map given by restricting the domain of cochains to simplicial chains, the last map existing because $C^{2n}_\Delta(S^n;\Bbb Z)$ is zero on the nose.

Comment: @mme This looks right to me, but wouldn't that prove that every space with a trivial cohomology ring is formal. Is that right?

Comment: @ConnorMalin Sure, but that's easy, right? The unit gives a quasi-iso from cohomology. The best I can do with this argument seems to be that if X is a simplicial complex whose integral cohomology groups are Z-free then $C^*(\Sigma X;\Bbb Z)$ is formal.

Comment: I agree with A.S.'s comment. (I interpreted 'trivial cohomology ring' as meaning $H^0 = H^*$; it seems like it was meant as 'all cup products are zero'. It is in general very hard to find cochains representing given cohomology classes whose products are zero on the nose, and I only know how to do this for suspensions.)

Comment: Sorry, I keep deleting my comments because they are not fleshed out enough to be as accurate and relevant as I would like. I will stop commenting on this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the simplicial set $\def\S{{\bf S}} \def\Sing{\mathop{\rm Sing}} \S^n=Δ^n/∂Δ^n$, which has exactly two nondegenerate simplices: a 0-simplex and an $n$-simplex.

Consider the map $\S^n→\Sing S^n$ that sends the only vertex of $\S^n$ to the given basepoint of $S^n$ and the only nondegenerate $n$-simplex of $\S^n$ to some singular $n$-simplex $Δ^n→S^n$ that sends the boundary to the basepoint and induces a degree 1 map once we mod out the boundary.

The map $\S^n→\Sing S^n$ is a simplicial weak equivalence.
Thus, the induced map on integral normalized simplicial cochains $\def\Z{{\bf Z}} \def\C{{\rm C}} \C(S^n,\Z)=\C(\Sing S^n,\Z)→\C(\S^n,\Z)$ is a quasi-isomorphism of augmented differential graded rings.

Observe that $\C(\S^n,\Z)$ is a differential graded ring
with exactly two generators: one in degree 0 and another one in degree $n$.  The differentials of both generators vanish.  Furthermore, the degree $n$ generator squares to 0 for dimensional reasons.
Thus, the normalized simplicial cochain ring $\C(\S^n,\Z)$ is precisely the graded cohomology ring $\def\H{{\rm H}} \H(S^n,\Z)$.